# Old Ceiling Junction Box Removal

Tags: lighting

Hey I just bought an older co-op from the 50’s. I want to put a ceiling fan in but ran into trouble.  I was trying to take down the existing box and it has a nipple in the middle with a flat head screw slot in the bottom.  I bought the usual box and anchor mechanism to put in but I have no idea how to get this box out.  Obviously I can't go in through the top due to the co-op situation.  Please help.  Maybe a YouTube video or something how to remove it. Thanks. [image]

Comment: I CANT go through the top due to the co-op situation.

Comment: The existing box may be the type which is rated for a hefty chandelier or a ceiling fan up to some specified weight. I think that large center screw clamps the box onto a metal crossbar which spans two joists.  How heavy is this ceiling fan?

Comment: I believe @JimStewart is on to something.  In other words, maybe revise the question to ask how to mount to it rather than ask how to remove it?

Answer (score 1):

Jim Stewart's comment is pretty much right on.

That is not a nipple it is what is called a "hickey" by the National Electrical Code. It serves to attach the box to a hanger bar or other spanning device.

It looks like you may have a pretty stout box already and may not need the fan box.

I usually look for a ceiling hugger style fan and toggle bolt it directly to the drywall/plaster. This eliminates the need for fan box.

Good luck!